# return the next cell with text in a range that includes blank cells

Tags: excel-2007

I have a formula that should return the next text filled cell in a range of cells from a different worksheet, but "#NUM!" is returned instead of the text.

=if(ROW()-ROW(NoBlanksRange)+1>ROWS(BlanksRange)-COUNTBLANK(BlanksRange),"",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(SMALL((IF(BlanksRange<>"",ROW(BlanksRange),ROW()+ROWS(BlanksRange))),ROW()-ROW(NoBlanksRange)+1),COLUMN(BlanksRange),1)))

Comment: I can't visualize your setup. Please give an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular formula:

```
=IF(ROWS(A$1:A1)>ROWS(NoBlanksRange),"",INDEX(BlanksRange,SMALL(INDEX((BlanksRange<>"")*ROW(BlanksRange)-ROW(INDEX(BlanksRange,1))+1,),COUNTBLANK(BlanksRange)+ROWS(A$1:A1))))
```